# FB Login: URL changes to random String after login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I tried to log in to Facebook as described on this site: 
http://www.codexworld.com/login-with-facebook-using-php/

So far it works really well. There’s just one thing I can’t find how to change myself.
When I successfully log in, the URL changes from `localhost/test/index.php` to having an extremely long random string attached at the end, like so:

`localhost/test/index.php?code=AQBEeF_j8ewNCrKfvAinFLxcqZJ4OLTI6K_
eUG0oxvBlk6MpZKprUiTyBMvDX6sIYdfOygzmJ7UgY_93pK2p6V8naGNCwgMnYLNQ8gqAgL-wur35vPB8gE0qX2XY9nJraFDZ7f6APDicM45J…-`

I don’t know what is responsible for this. But my callback URL is `localhost/test/`

Answer (score 1):

That's part of the Facebook login OAuth process. You should read the Facebook documentation on the login process and understand the various steps:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

> When `code` is received, it has to be exchanged for an access token using an endpoint. The call will need to be server-to-server, since it involves your app secret. (Your app secret should never end up in client code.)

<sup>Incidentally, skip that third-party tutorial, and get one [straight from the source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login). You'll have better results using Facebook's own examples. The one you've linked uses outdated techniques.</sup>

Comment: im just a beginner yet, can you help me to fix this? I cant really get out any meaning of the quoted phrase...

Comment: @OnFirE Facebook login uses OAuth. In OAuth, you send the user to Facebook to approve (or reject) the authorization. Facebook sends the user back to you with a `code` in the URL. Your server takes that code and requests an access token with it (and a secret parameter, so no one else can get it) from Facebook. Multi-step process, in which `code` plays a critical role.

Comment: well ok i understand that code is certainlly important, but how can i redirect to a index.php from login.php without the code in the url? or at least remove / overwrite it?

Comment: @OnFirE `if($_GET['code']) { // redirect }`? Just make sure it's *after* you **process** `code`.